# error with email account setting up iCloud on MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud

when in initially began the iCloud setup on MacBook i put in wrong email address. I don't think i put in a password. Now i keep getting box that says it can't access iCloud . I have a proper username and password for apple id , iTunes etc which I want to use. How do i get rid of this wrong iCloud username?

Answer (score 1):

Try signing out of iCloud.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Choose the iCloud panel
3. Click Sign Out

[image: Screenshot iCloud Preferences]

Answer (score 0):

Try to logout from iCloud fro system preferences **Apple icon > System Preferences > iCloud** and Click Logout